# Confirm dialog box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, confirm-dialog

How can I apply confirm dialog box in below button in angularjs ?

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">Delete</button>
```

Just like this.

```
<span><a class="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')" href="delete/{{ item.id }}">Delete</span>
```

**Update**

Currently I am doing it like this

```
    function removeUser(index) {
      var isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure to delete this record ?");
      if(isConfirmed){
        vm.users.splice(index, 1);
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the snippets,

how your HTML should be,

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete this record ?" confirmed-click="removeUser($index)">Delete</button>
```

Please Include this directive in your custom angularjs file,

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
}])
```

Your angular scope based on your delete function mentioned above,

```
$scope.removeUser = function(index) {
    vm.users.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: bind was deprecated.
  
  use on instead.

Answer (score 10):

```
$scope.removeUser= function (ind){
 if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    alert("deleted"+ s);
    $window.location.href = 'delete/'+ s;
 }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/61/

Comment: Perfect answer!!

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the message bit from the delete action bit, that way you could reuse the confirm bit in other parts of your app:
I use a directive like so:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive("ngConfirmClick", [
  function() {
   return {
     priority: -1,
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function(e) {
          var message;
          message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;
          if (message && !confirm(message)) {
           e.stopImmediatePropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

then have your controller function with the delete action:

```
$scope.removeUser(index) {
  //do stuff
}
```

and in the View I would use ng-click:

```
<span><a class="button" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure?" ng-click="removeUser(item.id}}">Delete</span>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xJJFxjYeeHmDixAYPu4c?p=preview
You can create a directive for the dialog.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

   $scope.delete = function(id) {
     $window.location.href = 'delete/'+ id;
   }
 });

 app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
}])
```